# Junit string comparison failure

Tags: java

This is the source code for the class that has to be tested.
When i run the junit class it gives me two failures
although the expected and actual output are identical
why?

It is also true that both are strings,
so that should not be an issue?
I see in the junit console org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: java.lang.String@4d5b6aac but was: ss.week2.Setting@3e84448c

````
    
    private ThreeWayLamp testLamp;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        testLamp = new ThreeWayLamp();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testState() {
        assertEquals("OFF",testLamp.getStatus());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSequence() {
        testLamp.setNextStatus();
        assertEquals("LOW", testLamp.getStatus());
    }

} 
.............................................

    /**
     * @requires String userInput OFF,LOW,MEDIUM or HIGH
     * @ensures currentSetting=userInput
     * **/
    public void setStatus(String userInput) {
        if(userInput.equals("OFF")) {
            currentSetting=Setting.OFF;
        }       
        if(userInput.equals("LOW")) {
            System.out.println("Setting lamp to low");
            currentSetting=Setting.LOW;
        }
        if(userInput.equals("MEDIUM")) {
            currentSetting=Setting.MEDIUM;
        }
        if(userInput.equals("HIGH")) {
            currentSetting=Setting.HIGH;
        }
        

    
    public void setNextStatus() {
        switch(currentSetting) {
        case OFF:
            currentSetting=Setting.LOW;
            break;
        case LOW:
            currentSetting=Setting.MEDIUM;
            break;
        case MEDIUM:
            currentSetting=Setting.HIGH;
            break;
        case HIGH:
            currentSetting=Setting.OFF;
            break;
        }
        
        }
    }
    
    
    ```
````

Comment: After editing the question, you compare `String` to `Setting` enum, why they should be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the code for `getStatus()` but the error message implies that it returns a `Setting`, not a `String`. Hence you need to do

```
assertEquals(Setting.OFF, testLamp.getStatus());
```

Comment: it does not recognize setting although i import the class in the junit test class

Comment: ```public Setting getStatus(){
  return currentSetting;
  } ```

Comment: ``` private static Setting currentSetting; ```

Comment: You simply do not show enough code for more detailed guidance. For all we know, `Setting` could be an inner class and you need to say `ThreeWayLamp.Setting`.